# Can I use views_bulk_operations with the Drupal 7 core toolbar module?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm building a drupal site right now where I'd prefer to use views_bulk_operations to administer the standard content overview (admin/content) and user overview pages (admin/people). My trouble is that I also want to use the toolbar module (or something like it) to give my site admins the ability to easily browse to the pages generated by views_bulk_operations (admin/content2 and admin/people2). It doesn't seem possible right now. The toolbar module automatically adds pre-defined links based on a users permissions, and there doesn't appear to be a way to make any changes to those links.

Any ideas? Or, perhaps, any alternatives to the core toolbar module? Thanks!

(I asked the same question [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/can-i-use-views-bulk-operations-with-the-d7-core-toolbar-module), but thought I'd have a better chance here on stackoverflow.)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that I can use the [quickbar](http://drupal.org/project/quickbar) module to accomplish what I want.